# I'm having trouble training a Tensorflow model

Tags: tensorflow, data-science

I am a beginner in TensorFlow. I have 9090 training data and 3897 test data. However, it's only using 37 data points to train the model.

[image]

I followed the same steps in the tensorflow training I followed. I checked it twice, but I couldn't find the error

Comment: A search on this site would have gotten you an answer without asking a question, please search before you ask.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using your full data. Batch size is 250, so it is 37 batches of data (9090 / 250 = 36.36 ~ 37).

Comment: Oh thank you. The video I was watching said 9090 \ 9090. That's why I was confused.